# appending elements in loop only appear once..jquery

Tags: jquery

jQuery 3.3.1

I have a bootstrap modal ad I want to dynamically add elements. I have the following:

```
 $('#somemodal .modal-body').empty();
   var data = {
            'foo': 'bar',
            'foo2': 'baz'
        }
  var s = $('<select />');

        for(var val in data) {
            $('<option />', {value: val, text: data[val]}).appendTo(s);
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            var div = $('<div/>');
            s.appendTo(div);
            $('#somemodal .modal-body').append(s);
        }


        $('#somemodal').modal({ show: true });
```

When i run this, only one select is inside of my modal when there should be 3. The html inside of my modal-body is being overwritten instead of appended to. How do I achieve my desired result by having the number of select elements appear inside of my modal based on the number of iterations instead of showing just one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `s.appendTo(div);` keeps moving the same `<select>` to a different `<div>` each iteration. When you `append()` an element(s) it does not make a copy...it just moves it

Clone the select to create a new one for each iteration

```
s.clone().appendTo(div);
```

Also you want to append the new `<div>` not the `<select>` to the modal body

```
$('#somemodal .modal-body').append(div);
```

Comment: I still get the same result

Comment: Ooo yeah! ... need to append the `<div>` ...change `$('#somemodal .modal-body').append(s);` to `$('#somemodal .modal-body').append(div);`